# Best way to create new DateTime column from VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, datetime, casting, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 1M rows and a `CREATED_AT varchar` column. The formatting of the date string in this column:

- 2021-10-13 05:03:42.638+00
- 2021-10-18 21:28:49.98+00
- 2021-12-08 02:09:03.17+00

I want to cast this string into a new `datetime` column (called `CREATED_DT`).

**Attempts**

```
select 
    cast([CREATED_AT] as datetime) 
from
    [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
select 
    convert(datetime, [CREATED_AT]) 
from 
    [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
select 
    try_convert(DateTime, [CREATED_AT]) 
from
    [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

Query executes, but returns all nulls.

```
select 
    try_convert(DateTime, [CREATED_AT], 108) 
from
    [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

Query executes, but returns all nulls.

```
select 
    try_cast([CREATED_AT] as datetime) 
from
    [mydb].[dbo].[mytable]
```

Query executes, but returns all nulls.

Comment: Use `TRY_CONVERT` and a style code, but really you should be fixing your design; never store date and time values as a `varchar`.

Comment: I am not the data owner for this one, separate system/org.  Will investigate TRY_CONVERT, new to me. Thanks

Comment: Can you define "best"? And can you make sure you include all possible edge cases (e.g. with only 1 or 0 decimal places, or missing the +00, or if any offset other than +00 needs to be observed), and indicate whether losing precision is ok (.638 can never be stored as a datetime, for example). There are all kinds of garbage data possible unless you push back on this system/org to provide proper, unambiguous date formats for the system that's consuming them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you never have to care about the useless `+00` at the end (either it's always `+00` or you don't care if it's ever something else), and you're ok losing a tiny bit of precision, you can take the left 22 characters and try to convert the values with a safe style number (in your case, 120):

```
DECLARE @d table(CREATED_AT varchar(32));

INSERT @d(CREATED_AT) VALUES
('2021-10-13 05:03:42.638+00'),
('2021-10-18 21:28:49.98+00'),
('2021-12-08 02:09:03.17+00');

SELECT CREATED_AT, 
  as_datetime = TRY_CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CREATED_AT, 22), 120) 
FROM @d;
```

If you don't want to lose the precision (you can't keep `.638` as `datetime`, anyway, for example), or if some value might have 1 or 0 decimal places, or some values might not contain the `+xx` at all, you can do something similar but use some string tricks to truncate the value where the `+` appears (and also handles if it doesn't):

```
SELECT CREATED_AT,
  as_datetime2 = TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(3), 
    LEFT(CREATED_AT, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('+', 
    CREATED_AT), 0), 32)-1), 120) 
FROM @d;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3a79b4180d8627f3fc36f877be61e83)

And to demonstrate why using the 120 style number is important here, see [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6c1c713cbbc00b000cd4af4634b3ffe7).

Comment: This worked a charm, and thanks for the dbfiddle.  Learnt a few thngs from this.  Much appreciated.  Happy 2022!

Answer (score 2):

The style you are looking for is `127`, but your issue is that you only include the hour for the time-zone, you also need minutes. So just add `:00` to each value.

You can then convert to a regular `datetime` from there, by using `SWITCHOFFSET`

```sql
DECLARE @v varchar(30) = '2021-10-13 05:03:42.638+00';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset, @v + ':00', 127);

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset, @v + ':00', 127), 0));
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d8278d465380f352ff4725b51f4b6f4)